# Find the dimension of the nullspace and basis of the following $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be the vector space of polynomials of degree at most 999 with real coefficients. Define a linear map:

$T:V\rightarrow\mathbb{R^{100}}\ $ where $T(p) = (p(1),p(2),......,p(100))\ $ ($p$ evaluated at 1, 2, ...., 100).

Find the dimension of the nullspace and range.

Below is the outline of my attempt.

I wanted to use rank-nullity theorem, dim($V$) = 1000, dim($\mathbb{R^{100}}$) = 100, thus by rank-nullity theorem dim(N($T$)) = 900.

But as you probably can tell, I'm missing am important lemma, that $T$ is surjective. So my question is:

If my attempt is right, how to I prove surjectivity of $T$.

If my attempt is wrong, how should I approach this question ?

Any help or insight is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Surjectivity actually follows from polynomial interpolation, the Vandermonde method. If you give me the values of $p(1),...,p(100)$, I can create a polynomial of degree 100 taking exactly these values.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea about how to approach it, using polynomial interpolation. The polynomial

$$p(x) = A(x - 2)(x - 3)(x - 4)\cdots(x - 100)$$

can take any value you please at $x = 1$ by careful choice of $A$ and is $0$ at $x = 2, 3, ..., 100$.

Modify this example to take the value you want at $x = 2$, and add the two polynomials you got. You can now specify their values at two points.

Continue as needed, and conclude that you don't actually need degree $999$, but degree $99$ is good enough.